# Magento - add new catalog_product attribute

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

I want to add a new product attribute and am using code similar to this:

```
/**
 * @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup
 */
$installer = $this;

$attribute = array(
    'label'             => 'New Attribute',
    'required'          => false,
    'type'              => 'varchar',
    'input'             => 'text'
);
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'new_attribute', $attribute);
```

Which works fine.

But, I want to add this attribute to a specific attribute set and ONLY to this specific attribute set.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the `$attributeSetId`, the procedure is as follows:

1. Get the $attributeId
2. Get the Attribute group Id of the attribute set
   (e.g. the "General" group)
3. Add the attribute to the set and group

For example

```
        $attributeId = $installer->getAttributeId(
            'catalog_product', 
            'new_attribute'
        );

        $attributeGroupId = $installer->getAttributeGroup(
            'catalog_product',
            $attributeSetId,
            'General'
        );

        $installer->addAttributeToSet(
            'catalog_product',
            $attributeSetId, 
            $attributeGroupId,
            $attributeId 
        );
```

Comment: In that case, there is not a way to do this with some configuration values passed to the addAttribute method call?

Comment: Not to a specific one, no. If you provide a group id in the attribute data array, or leave the property `user_defined` empty, then the attribute will be automatically added to every set belonging to its entity type. See here https://github.com/varinen/solvingmagento_1.7.0/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Setup.php#L669